# Effectively classifying a DB of event logs by a column

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

### Situation

I am using Python 3.7.2 with its built-in sqlite3 module. (sqlite3.version == 2.6.0)

I have a sqlite database that looks like:

```
| user_id | action | timestamp  |
| ------- | ------ | ---------- |
| Alice   |      0 | 1551683796 |
| Alice   |     23 | 1551683797 |
| James   |      1 | 1551683798 |
| ....... | ...... | .......... |
```

where `user_id` is `TEXT`, `action` is an arbitary `INTEGER`, and `timestamp` is an `INTEGER` representing UNIX time.

The database has 200M rows, and there are 70K distinct `user_id`s.

### Goal

I need to make a Python dictionary that looks like:

```py
{
    "Alice":[(0, 1551683796), (23, 1551683797)],
    "James":[(1, 1551683798)],
    ...
}
```

that has `user_id`s as keys and respective event logs as values, which are lists of tuples `(action, timestamp)`. Hopefully each list will be sorted by `timestamp` in increasing order, but even if it isn't, I think it can be easily achieved by sorting each list after a dictionary is made.

### Effort

I have the following code to query the database. It first queries for the list of users (with `user_list_cursor`), and then query for all rows belonging to the user.

```py
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
user_list_cursor = connection.cursor()
user_list_cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM EVENT_LOG")
user_id = user_list_cursor.fetchone()

classified_log = {}
log_cursor = connection.cursor()
while user_id:
    user_id = user_id[0] # cursor.fetchone() returns a tuple
    query = (
        "SELECT action, timestamp"
        " FROM TABLE"
        " WHERE user_id = ?"
        " ORDER BY timestamp ASC"
    )
    parameters = (user_id,)
    local_cursor.execute(query, parameters) # Here is the bottleneck
    classified_log[user_id] = list()
    for row in local_cursor.fetchall():
        classified_log[user_id].append(row)
        user_id = user_list_cursor.fetchone()
```

### Problem

The query execution for each user is too slow. That single line of code (which is commented as *bottleneck*) takes around 10 seconds for each `user_id`. I think I am making a wrong approach with the queries. What is the right way to achieve the goal?

I tried searching with keywords "classify db by a column", "classify sql by a column", "sql log to dictionary python", but nothing seems to match my situation. I think this wouldn't be a rare need, so maybe I'm missing the right keyword to search with.

### Reproducibility

If anyone is willing to reproduce the situation with a 200M row sqlite database, the following code will create a 5GB database file.

But I hope there is somebody who is familiar with such a situation and knows how to write the right query.

```py
import sqlite3
import random

connection = sqlite3.connect("tmp.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENT_LOG (user_id TEXT, action INTEGER, timestamp INTEGER)"
)
query = "INSERT INTO EVENT_LOG VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
parameters = []
for timestamp in range(200_000_000):
    user_id = f"user{random.randint(0, 70000)}"
    action = random.randint(0, 1_000_000)
    parameters.append((user_id, action, timestamp))
cursor.executemany(query, parameters)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, my misunderstanding. Removed the phrase from the question.

Comment: You need to [use indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23572342).

Comment: If I was doing this in PHP (the only application code I know), I'd simply select the entire data set, ordered by user, and then parse the resulting array. That's surely quicker than executing a separate query for each user.

Comment: @Solarflare: Thanks, now the performance increased to 30-50 `user_id`s per second. Now I'm going to try @Strawberry 's solution to see if it helps furthur.

Comment: I tried reading the whole table `ORDER BY  user_id ASEC`, but it seems to lag too much, probably because it's just too big, can't fit in my physical memory, thus using virtual memory of tens of GBs. I think I should go with indexing, although I wish it could be even faster... @Solarflare, I will accept your answer if you want to post one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @Strawberry and @Solarflare for their help given in comments.

The following solution achieved more than 70X performance increase, so I'm leaving what I did as an answer for completeness' sake.

I used indices and queried for the whole table, as they suggested.

```py
import sqlite3
from operators import attrgetter

connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

# Creating index, thanks to @Solarflare
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_user_id ON EVENT_LOG (user_id)")
cursor.commit()

# Reading the whole table, then make lists by user_id. Thanks to @Strawberry
cursor.execute("SELECT user_id, action, timestamp FROM EVENT_LOG ORDER BY user_id ASC")
previous_user_id = None
log_per_user = list()
classified_log = dict()
for row in cursor:
    user_id, action, timestamp = row
    if user_id != previous_user_id:
        if previous_user_id:
            log_per_user.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
            classified_log[previous_user_id] = log_per_user[:]
        log_per_user = list()
    log_per_user.append((action, timestamp))
    previous_user_id = user_id
```

So the points are

- Indexing by `user_id` to make `ORDER BY user_id ASC` execute in acceptable time.
- Reading the whole table, then classify by `user_id`, instead of making individual queries for each `user_id`.
- Iterating over `cursor` to read row by row, instead of `cursor.fetchall()`.